# Correct English: "Get sick" or "fall sick"

Tags: word-usage

Whats the correct English
"I got sick last night" or "I fell sick last night"?

Comment: In the UK it is more common to hear "I felt sick last night" or "I was sick last night".

Comment: Have you tried looking up the words in a dictionary or even just on Google; or in some other way tried to find an answer to your question before asking here? If so, please include what you have already looked through and why that wasn’t a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 5):

(For whatever reason...) In the US we say "got sick" and "fell ill". Although, "falling ill" implies that it's just the start of something that's going to turn out to be much more serious and long term - Like: "He *got sick* with the flu, last week," as opposed to "She *fell ill* with cancer, as soon as they returned from the trip."

Of course, "fell sick", also implies something ongoing - so, I guess it's the "fell" part that makes it seem like something lengthy. "Got ill" (not very common - but still used) usually just means "vomited".)

Comment: If [this Ngram](http://bit.ly/17tGELS) is anything to go by, _get sick_ is more common than _fall ill_ by a long way—but until around 1850, _fall sick_ was actually the **most** common of the lot, while _get ill_ has been consistently quite limited. [The same in BrE](http://bit.ly/17tGZ18) shows quite a lot more variation, though _get sick_ and _fall ill_ are still the most common nowadays. (Although I’d say that in BrE, vomiting is always _sick_, never _ill_. “He was sick in the bushes” = “He vomited in the bushes” ≠ “He was ill in the bushes”.)

Comment: Benjy: "I think I'm going to be unwell."  Alan Swann: "Ladies are 'unwell', my dear boy... Gentlemen 'vomit'."  --"My Favorite Year" (MGM, 1982)